# iOS release app no longer available on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-developer

I was using the release version of my flutter app on my iPhone from a few days. And suddenly now it’s is saying “app is no longer available” when I try to open.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will no longer appear on the app store if you dont have an active developer licence. if you didnt put it on the app store and just gave it to them via ad hoc or something, the provisioning profile has probably expired so you would need to renew that, which would need an active developer licence as well.

Comment: So I cannot use my own apps for free? Without publishing to store?

Comment: To use your own apps on physical devices, you will need a paid developer program membership. Publishing on the app strore is not required, there are other ways of distribution like ad-hoc builds.

Comment: @Aether sign with non membership account is only on your device in 7days if I remember. That’s why you got the issue. You  have to resign it again to extend the duration.